# Office Web Apps on SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-web-apps

I have followed every guide that I can find - but I can't get Office Web Apps to work on SharePoint 2013.

When I try to open a document, it starts to load but then I get an error.  It then continues to try and load indefinitely.

How can I troubleshoot this?

[image]

Here is the output from the log:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can double check your setup here: [Office Web Apps](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431687(v=office.15).aspx).

I had the same issue where one of my Web Applications were working and the other was giving the same issue that you are receiving.

Double check your certificates between your SharePoint server and your Office Web Apps server.

Comment: I have read that article like 10 times lol - what certificates?  I am using SSL offloading to create my web apps far (New-OfficeWebAppsFarm –InternalURL "http://office.yeack.local" -ExternalURL "https://office.yeack.com" -AllowHttp -EditingEnabled:$true -SSLOffloaded:$true) - so my understanding is that I only have to have my SSL certificate on my IIS ARR - or are you talking about a different type of certificate?

Comment: If you go to the server where OWA is running on. go to your SharePoint site and try open the document from their. Check your logs for any OWA or Server Error related entries

Comment: I added a screenshot of a log entry -

Comment: Looking at the logs in the picture. It says "Unable to determine zone from request" and further down you see "Is authenticated: False". This indicates that you should check: A) Firewall or trust relationship between your servers. B) Have you got a host file entry for your SharePoint server on the OWA server? ("C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\")

Comment: Why would I have a host file entry?  The SharePoint site can be resolved via DNS from OWA...as in I can see it if I load it in a browser..